# Displaying a value from database table

Tags: php

This is my PHP code:

```
$query4=mysql_query("select * from quiz
                     where `group`='$token'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row4=mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)){
    echo $row4['quiz_no'];
}
```

I have a 3 row on my table quiz_no 1 1 2

but I want to display it like this:

```
Quiz no. 1
Quiz no. 2
```

but it keeps displaying

```
1
1
2
```

Comment: `echo 'Quiz no.' . $row4['quiz_no'];`?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` to get unique results and concatenate the words `Quiz no.` to your echo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only distinct objects. Your query can be changed to:

```
select distinct quiz_no from quiz where `group`='$token'
```

Note that this is *not* a safe method for performing a database query, as it is subject to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Something like the following would be preferred:

```
$query = sprintf("select distinct quiz_no from quiz where `group`='%s'",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($token));
mysql_query($query);
```

If you want to achieve your desired output, you will need to echo the "Quiz no." manually:

```
echo "Quiz no. " . $row4['quiz_no'];
```

Comment: Something I've never been entirely sure of is `DISTINCT *` - TBH, I haven't found anything that contradicts it or permits it, yet MySQL states `SELECT DISTINCT column` - You also seem to have a syntax error in the `sprintf` version. Stack's syntax highlighting is complaining.

Comment: when i use 'select distinct *' it will only output error but when i use 'select distinct quiz_no' but i also need the other value

Comment: I forgot to update the query. I corrected it above, thanks for the correction. Remo - What is the "other value" you need? If it is the group, you already have that...

Comment: Maybe OP can use `select distinct column *,` I think that is allowed. Can also use `GROUP BY`. Or just tack on another column to `DISTINCT`. `select distinct column1, column2`

Comment: Ideally, once you extend distinct beyond one column I think you would want to start using joins or groups. However, this functionality is generally a reflection of poor database design. When I see a need to have multiple distinct columns in a query (but not in the database!), I typically see that as a need to normalize the database design, which generally eliminates the problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend the string "Quiz no." while echo'ing the quiz number and use DISTINCT

```
<?php
    $query4=mysql_query("select distinct * from quiz where `group`='$token'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row4=mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)){
        echo "Quiz no. " . $row4['quiz_no'] ."\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Read the question and code again. OP wants Quiz no. 1 and 2 and not `1-1-2`